# Android Application terminates suddenly on emulator with API 23

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have been developing a very simple android application with a webview loading a website in it.

I am testing this app on 2-3 emulators. But from last 2 days in has been crashing on one of the emulators with no error thrown. I was about to publish this app on Google play but this thing has stopped me and I could not figure out what is the problem.

Following are the print screens of the log I get when I run the app on emulator on which it crashes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgftX.jpg

The emulator on which it crashes has following configuration:

Nexus 6P Edited

5.7 1440x2560 xxhdpi

Marshmallow

Android 6.0 x86

Graphics: Software - GLES 2.0

RAM: 512

VM Heap: 64

Internal Storage: 800

SD Card:" Studio Managed 100 MB

Custom skin: Nexus_6P

I have uploaded ANdroid Monitor Log in .txt format at:
http://www.filedropper.com/androidmonitorlog

It happens only when I select Google API x86 image, otherwise if I select x86 image it works fine

Comment: Please provide screenshots of log in android monitor

Comment: @kumargaurav I have edited the question with link to the Android Monitor log